# Bullets repeat numbers when forcing text to two columns in rmarkdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I am trying to get two columns of text in my slide in isolides by:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 40%;">
1.    Threaded couplers (TC)
2.    Headed bar couplers (HBC)
3.    Bar-grip (swaged) couplers (BSC)
</div>

<div style="float: right; width: 60%;">
4.    Shear screw couplers (SSC)
5.    Grouted sleeve couplers (GSC)
</div>
```

But the results I get is:

[image]

Comment: You're using two lists right? That is expected behaviour

Comment: if you are using a list look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li and search for the li attribute `value` , but you should use a CSS counter to avoid dealing with the value attribute : see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter() . there is also CSS column to split a list into columns : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns

Comment: @Paulie_D I only want one list. This the text in my slide and I just want to divide it up into two columns

Comment: so use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns seems to be what you need:

> CSS Multi-column Layout is a module of CSS that adds support for multi-column layouts. Support is included for establishing the number of columns in a layout, as well as how content should flow from column to column, gap sizes between columns, and column dividing lines (known as column rules) along with their appearance.

example

```css
ol {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

You can shrink it  and set columns to max-width of an item:

```css
ol {
  column-count: 2;
  width: max-content;
  column-gap: 2em;
  border: solid;
}

li {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item longer</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```