# Stack DIVs in multiple columns following the order they are typed

Tags: html, css

[image]

Given a list of elements like this:

```
<div>
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
</div>
```

I would like to achieve the result in the picture above. I tried to use flexboxes using "flex:50%" for every child element but all I was able to achieve is this.

[image]

Is there a clean way to achieve this without using more divs ?

Comment: [more dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=flex+2+columns+vertical+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: another similar one from today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222284/bullets-repeat-numbers-when-forcing-text-to-two-columns-in-rmarkdown